# Finding a Registry Key In Order to Delete It

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, malware, dll

A couple of months ago, I acquired some lovely malware. After removing this (lovely) malware  I received a pop message, further improving my day. The message indicates that there was a problem starting (bogus) file tosendto.dll, because the file could not be found.

Searching the registry with the phrase "tosendto.dll" does not yield any results. This error seems to be significantly impacting my computer's performance, and I'm out of ideas to find the key invoking the file. Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you ran a scan with an anti-virus program like Anti-Malwarebytes, Super Anti-Spyware, Avast, etc? Malwarebytes is good at removing PUPs (Potentially Unwanted Programs) and other files that you seem to be having trouble with.

Comment: There is an identical question (unfortunately no answer) at http://superuser.com/questions/982168/.  I agree with the consensus that something remains of the malware.  More detail would definitely help.  What did you use to remove the malware?  And when exactly does the message about tosendto.dll pop up (at startup, or when you do a particular action)?

Comment: It means there is some entry in your registry that is attempting to load a program that uses it.  You can use a program like Autoruns to find what programs are starting automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to guess that the file's name is probably encoded in a way that might be challenging to find, possibly using a binary value instead of a string value. I would personally recommend [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)'s registry cleaner feature, which finds invalid registry entries, and cleans them up for you. There are other tools out there that do this as well, but since I usually look for the least expensive solution, which in this case, is free, CCleaner is usually the first tool I turn to when I need to fix registry errors involving missing DLL files, etc.

(Disclaimer: I am not, nor have ever, been employed or affiliated with piriform, I just like their software.)

(Note: This assumes you have *successfully* removed the malware. Make sure you've used a malware scanner first, because CCleaner doesn't do that.)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to explain how malware works, please have a look at the very well written answers in this article:
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Please don't link to other [SU] questions and answers. Instead flag this question as a duplicate.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.